# DaveJamesMiller Breadcrumbs Error - Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5, breadcrumbs

I am currently trying to set up `breadcrumbs` for my `Laravel 5` application. Unfortunately, I am currently being presented with this error when I access `localhost:8888/auth/login`:

> ErrorException in
>   /Users/ben/Sites/laravel/vendor/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/src/CurrentRoute.php
>   line 29
>
> The current route (GET /auth/login) is not named - please check
>   routes.php for an "as" parameter

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin',
['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth/AuthController@getLogin']);
```

The error is shown with or without the `['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth/AuthController@getLogin']` addition.

Breadcrumbs.php

```
Breadcrumbs::register('login', function($breadcrumbs)
{
    $breadcrumbs->parent('home');
    $breadcrumbs->push('Login', route('login'));
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing the route to the following:

```
Route::get('auth/login',
    ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth/AuthController@getLogin']);
```

You can only declare which controller method you're using once.